# A good approach to read image files in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am planning to develop a system that can load and process image files in C++. Before coding the system, I wanted to focus on software engineering and OOP side of the project.

My question is how would you design basic image loading part of this system? Here is my class structure:

In image.hpp file, I wanted to have a class that contains basic things to represent all image files in the memory.

```
// image.hpp

class image {
private:
    unsigned int size;
protected:
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    uint8_t * raw;
public:
    image();
    image(const image& obj);
    unsigned int getWidth() { return width; }
    unsigned int getHeight(){ return height; }
    virtual ~image();
    virtual bool load(const std::string &fileName) = 0;
};
```

In tga.hpp file, I totally focused on TGA specific operations.

```
// tga.hpp
typedef struct {
    uint8_t  idLength;
    uint8_t  colorMapType;
    uint8_t  imageType;
    uint16_t colorMapOrigin;
    uint16_t colorMapLength;
    uint8_t  colorMapDepth;
    uint16_t xOrigin;
    uint16_t yOrigin;
    uint16_t width;
    uint16_t height;
    uint8_t  bitsPerPixel;
    uint8_t  imageDescriptor;
} tgaHeader;

class tga: public image {
private:
    tgaHeader header;
protected:
public:
    bool load(const std::string &fileName);
};
```

Do you think this is a good approach? --I don't think so...

BTW, I tried to find an example before asking this question but I even couldn't find a keyword to read an article written on those kinds of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use one of the existing myriad of libraries for loading images? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I see your point but the idea behind this question is to get "OOP culture". Actually, this is not a real project but an experimental one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest externalizing the loader, making it separate and outside of your abstract 'image' class. The client will probably expect that any public 'load' function he sees at this abstract level will be capable of loading a set number of supported image formats without varying capabilities for each 'image' subtype.

Rationale: you probably want to be able to load a variety of image formats, and probably don't want to deal with the pain of handling every possible format in every possible 'image' subtype.

If you have cases where specific file formats like TGA should construct a 'tga' instance and requires internal details of this 'tga' class to be understood, I would suggest a non-virtual approach like allowing 'tga' to be constructed with a tga file via a parameterized constructor.

Finally, if you need a generalized "load whatever" function, you can create it like so with a factory method outside of your classes:

```
unique_ptr<image> load_image(const string& file)
{
    if (extension_of(file) == "tga")
        return unique_ptr<image>(new tga(file));
    ...
}
```

Of course you can also put this as a static method of your 'image' class or into some other 'image_loader' kind of class if you prefer.

If you want an extensible loader design here, then you can start mapping file format extensions/header info to function objects which return a new image based on the file or file data passed in. Then you can avoid modifying this central 'load_image' function each time you provide a new image type and support a new format.

In any case, try to avoid virtual methods if you cannot find a good way to provide meaningful and consistent behavior for every subclass that overrides it. It's also generally useful to look for reasons not to include something in a public interface and seek to add it elsewhere if you want to establish more stable (unchanging) designs more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would question the need to define a child class of image that contains header info. Most libraries just have an image object containing pixel values and size of the dimensions. You could have a helper function that returns a header struct if needed.

If we look at CImg it has a load method that checks the extension and calls the appropriate loader method. The loader then sets the data and size members.